# Make single column of numpy array another datatype

Tags: python, numpy

Given a numpy array `my_arr` filled with strings, how do I set the datatype of one of the columns to be float? I need it as an numpy array in order to use it with my existing code afterwards. See example of a failed attempt below:

```
import numpy as np

dat = [['User1', 'Male', '2.2'], ['User2', 'Female', '3.777'], ['User3', 'Unknown', '0.0']]
my_arr = np.array(dat)
print my_arr
# [['User1' 'Male' '2.2'], ['User2' 'Female' '3.777'], ['User3' 'Unknown' '0.0']]

my_arr[:,2] = my_arr[:,2].astype(np.float)
print my_arr
# [['User1' 'Male' '2.2'], ['User2' 'Female' '3.777'], ['User3' 'Unknown' '0.0']]
```

Comment: What kind of strings do you have? Something like "2.3", "7.89" or "myString", "myString2"? And what do you mean by "without success"? What went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be smarter ways on doing this but the following gives you the correct output I think; you can use [structured arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html):

```
import numpy as np
dat = [['User1', 'Male', '2.2'], ['User2', 'Female', '3.777'], ['User3', 'Unknown', '0.0']]

# create data types: two strings of length 10 and float
dt = np.dtype('a10, a10, float')

# convert the inner lists to tuples so that a structured array can be used
for ind, l in enumerate(dat):
    dat[ind] = tuple(l)

# convert dat to an array
my_arr = np.array(dat, dt)
```

Output:

```
array([('User1', 'Male', 2.2), ('User2', 'Female', 3.777),
       ('User3', 'Unknown', 0.0)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S10'), ('f1', 'S10'), ('f2', '<f8')])
```

You can also give names to the columns by doing:

```
dt = {'names': ['user', 'gender', 'number'], 'formats':['a10', 'a10', 'float']}
my_arr = np.array(dat, dt)  # dat is the list with tuples, see above
```

The output now is:

```
array([('User1', 'Male', 2.2), ('User2', 'Female', 3.777),
       ('User3', 'Unknown', 0.0)], 
      dtype=[('user', 'S10'), ('gender', 'S10'), ('number', '<f8')])
```

And you can then access a single column by doing e.g.

```
my_arr['number']
array([ 2.2  ,  3.777,  0.   ])

my_arr['user']
array(['User1', 'User2', 'User3'], dtype='|S10')
```

I would recommend to use a dataframe from Python [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html) where you can easily deal with different data types and complex data structures.

For your example:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(dat, columns=['user', 'gender', 'some number'])
```

would then simply give you:

```
    user   gender some number
0  User1     Male         2.2
1  User2   Female       3.777
2  User3  Unknown         0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

You could convert your 2d array into a structured array with a mixed `dtype`:

```
In [137]: my_arr
Out[137]: 
array([['User1', 'Male', '2.2'],
       ['User2', 'Female', '3.777'],
       ['User3', 'Unknown', '0.0']], 
      dtype='<U7')

In [138]: dt=np.dtype('U7,U7,f')  # complex dtype

In [139]: np.array([tuple(row) for row in my_arr], dtype=dt)
Out[139]: 
array([('User1', 'Male', 2.200000047683716),
       ('User2', 'Female', 3.7769999504089355), ('User3', 'Unknown', 0.0)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<U7'), ('f1', '<U7'), ('f2', '<f4')])

In [140]: _.shape
Out[140]: (3,)
```

Now it is a `1d` array with 3 fields.  Instead of accessing columns by number you access fields by name, `arr['f0']` etc.

I used `[tuple(row) for row in my_arr]` because the input to structured arrays has to be a list of tuples.  I could have used your `dat` list, `[tuple(row) for row in dat]`.